Which algorithms can predict the next number in a sequence with price fluctuations?
What are the most effective algorithms for predicting the next number in a sequence, specifically in the context of price fluctuations in financial markets, and how do these algorithms handle trends, volatility, and noise in the data?

There is no such algorithm. See the "no free lunch" theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem.  To be effective, any algorithm will need to encode some priors, either explicitly or implicitly, and the effectiveness will depend on how well the priors match the actual truth.
